# my attempt at kernel-based image processing with p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

```js
var imagething;
var kernel = [[1, 2, 1], [2, 4, 2], [1, 2, 1]];
var sum_of_elements = 0;
var mult_factor = 0.0625;
var bias = 0;

function preload() {
 imagething = loadImage('data/image.png');
}

function setup() {
    createCanvas(1000, 1000);
    imagething.loadPixels();
    image(imagething, 0, 0);
    makeBlurred(imagething, 1);
    image(imagething, 512, 0);
}

function imageIndex(img, x, y) {
    return 4 * (x + y * img.width);
}

function makeBlurred() {
 for(var i = 0; i < kernel.length; i++) {
  for(var j = 0; j < kernel.length; j++) {
   sum_of_elements += kernel[i][j];
  }
 }
 for(var x = 0; x < imagething.width; x++) {
  for(var y = 0; y < imagething.height; y++) {
   var red = 0;
   var green = 0;
   var blue = 0;
   for(var i = 0; i < kernel.length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < kernel.length; j++) {
     var imageX = (x - kernel.length / 2 + i + imagething.width) % imagething.width; 
     var imageY = (y - kernel.length / 2 + j + imagething.height) % imagething.height; 
     var RGB = imageIndex(imagething, imageX, imageY);
     var pix = imagething.pixels;
     var R = pix[RGB];
     var G = pix[RGB + 1];
     var B = pix[RGB + 2];
     console.log("Start: ",R,G,B);
     red += (R * kernel[i][j]);
     green += (G * kernel[i][j]);
     blue += (B * kernel[i][j]);
    }
   }
   var outR;
   var outG;
   var outB;
   outR = Math.min(Math.max(Math.round(red * mult_factor), 0), 255);
   outG = Math.min(Math.max(Math.round(green * mult_factor), 0), 255);
   outB = Math.min(Math.max(Math.round(blue * mult_factor), 0), 255);
   console.log("End: ", outR, outG, outB);
   pix[RGB] = outR;
   pix[RGB + 1] = outG;
   pix[RGB + 2] = outB;
   imagething.updatePixels();
  }
 }
}
```

So I am referencing [this blog post](http://tech.abdulfatir.com/2014/05/kernel-image-processing.html) on kernel-based image processing and I am trying to blur my image. I am using the blur matrix and I use the [original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiGVD.png) image and it should turn out like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRmGQ.png) but it ends up like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0s5bv.png) so I must be doing something wrong. Help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Have you tried [debugging your code](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging)? Which line of code is behaving differently from what you expected?

Comment: My code has no errors and I have no idea which line of code is behaving differently.

Comment: That's why I'm asking you to debug your code. Step through it line-by-line, either with a piece of paper and a pencil, or with the debugger that comes with your browser. This is the only way to figure out the problem, and it's what you're asking us to do.